# Creating Setup FIle Using InstallShield

Tags: wpf, sqlite, installshield-le

I have a created a simple wpf desktop application which uses sqlite as embeddable database.Now I need to create the setup file. I created it using InstallShield. the file successfully installed without any errors. But when I try to run the application, nothing happens. Neither an error is thrown nor application runs. Also I didn't add any Sqlite dll(don't know how to add if its required). Can someone guide why I am having trouble

Comment: retry using ClickOnce to just find which is causing problem (InstallShield or the App)

Comment: I'll do that but anyways I need to add the Sqlite.dll file while creating setup file using Install SHield,right?How to do that

Comment: Setup project is basically going to detect all dependencies and add them to the install project.

Comment: Some of the files in the bin folder of my project were missing the installation directory. As soon as I copied those files, everything works fine. I think I am missing something while creating the setup file. Can you provide me the link, on how to create setup file in VS 2013

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verify your setup project is importing every dependency to the install package. [link1](http://kb.flexerasoftware.com/doc/Helpnet/installshield15helplib/IHelpMergeModules.htm) [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12378125/create-msi-or-setup-project-with-visual-studio-2012)

Comment: I included all the files and finally got it working. But now all the database operation are now taking way too much time as compared to when I was building or directly running the application from the bin folder. Whats the cause of this?

Comment: Also Updates to database are failing

Comment: Its because of the administrative rights. So should I ask the user to install the app in  a location where administrative rights are not required or is there a way where I can force the user to sign in as administrator  while installing the application

Comment: Yes, you can force the installation to run as an administrator.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9401525/how-can-i-make-the-installer-run-as-admin