# how i change out put folder permission?

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, installshield, file-permissions

i have project `install shield` with `visual studio 2012` my
connection string establish when user chose server and database name
i make `XML file` have this `configurations`  when i install my
application i can't modify in XML file due to not full control
`permission`  i have `limited Install shield`  any suggestions ?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sqbK1.png

Comment: What happens when you run your installer as administrator? You can force this, if I'm correct.

Comment: i have no option to run as administrator when  right click get no run as administrator

Comment: Right Click > Properties > Compatibility > "Run this program as an administrator"

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9401525/how-can-i-make-the-installer-run-as-admin

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to get admin privilege: [UAC self-elevation](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/CSUACSelfElevation-644673d3)