# Solving path access denied error in windows form app

Tags: vb.net

I used installShield LE 2015 to build my application's installer and is successful.  The problem am having now is that there's a Ms access db file in the installation location which i need to restore from the main application, but when i try to restore it, i get an error "Access to the path "C:\Program Files (x86)\RC record system\RecordSystemDb.accdb" is denied. Please someone should tell me how to resolve this issue.

Comment: either include the database into the installer or run the installer with admin rights.

Comment: I included the database with the installer. how do i run the installer wth admin right?

Comment: Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9401525/how-can-i-make-the-installer-run-as-admin)

Comment: C:\Program Files is protected by UAC.  Apps can read but not write files in any of its subdirectories unless they run elevated.  So it is very bad place to store a database.  Use AppData instead.  And do consider giving the user the option to put it on a well backed-up file server, loss of customer data is almost always disastrous.